# neo4j is not getting started

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

My neo4j is not getting started in centos 8. machine I am getting the failed error message.

1. yum install neo4j

   service neo4j start
   Starting neo4j (via systemctl):                            [  OK  ]
   service neo4j status
   ● neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-20 14:09:05 UTC; 3s ago
   Process: 35111 ExecStart=/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j console (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 35111 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

   Nov 20 14:09:05 db-india-internal systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
   Nov 20 14:09:05 db-india-internal systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
   Nov 20 14:09:05 db-india-internal systemd[1]: Stopped Neo4j Graph Database.
   Nov 20 14:09:05 db-india-internal systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
   Nov 20 14:09:05 db-india-internal systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
   Nov 20 14:09:05 db-india-internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Neo4j Graph Database.

how to fix this error. Also how to use the already existing db data.

Comment: What is the version of the Neo4j server?
Can you expand on what you mean with "how to use the already existing db data"?

Comment: yum list --show neo4j CentOS-8 - openlogic packages for x86_64                                                                                                 
Neo4j RPM Repository                                                                                                                     Installed Packages
neo4j.noarch       4.2.0-1                                                                   @neo4j

Comment: I have the db already how should I addit in the new azure vm where the neo4j is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I didnt fix the bug instead I reinstalled the neo4j

```
> yum remove neo4j-4.2.0-1.noarch 
> systemctl enable neo4j
>  service neo4j start
> service neo4j status
```

And then it start running.